# Switch current network to "Home" mode from the command line

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

Is there a way to switch between Home, Public, and Work modes from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear to be possible from the "regular" command line (unless the netsh command does what you need, see Nixphoe's answer), but if you on't mind using PowerShell for what ever it is you're doing then you can have a look at this [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/setting-network-location-to-private/) on MSDN.

Basically, Vista had a COM based api which you could use PowerShell to interact with. I assume it is still there in Win7. The blog post includes a sample script.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [netsh](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee851674.aspx). Here's some [examples](http://www.petri.co.il/configure_tcp_ip_from_cmd.htm). You would want to dump your config to a file

```
netsh -c interface dump > c:'location1.txt
```

Then import it depending on where you're located.

```
netsh -f c:'location1.txt
```

Comment: The dumped settings don't seem to have any mention of network type setting, am I missing something?